# Build an associative array from an input data

Tags: bash, awk

I need to build an associative array from an input. I have used that script but does not work properly:

```
declare -A map

data="aa|AA"

echo $data | awk -F"|" '{ map[$1] = $2 }'

for i in "${!map[@]}"; do
    echo "${map[$i]}"
done
```

Could you provide a solution for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work properly? What do you want to happen?

Comment: map is empty, there  is no value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you created an associative array in `awk`, not in the shell.

You can create an associative array in the shell like this:

```
while IFS='|' read k v; do map[$k]=$v; done <<< $data
```

As I understand, your input can be complex, so you would like to process it using `awk`, and then populate an associate array in the shell to use it later in your script. Although `awk` and the shell cannot share variables, a possible workaround is to output variable assignments with `awk` which you can wrap in an `eval`:

```
eval $(printf "aa|AA\nbb|BB\n" | awk -F"|" '{ map[$1] = $2 } END { for (k in map) print "map[" k "]=" map[k] }')
```

So that you get:

```
$ for i in ${!map[@]}; do echo $i=${map[$i]}; done
aa=AA
bb=BB
```

Comment: At all I need an awk command, so that I can filter data coloumns. Assume that there can be 3 or more value and I want $1 for key and $3 for value

Comment: Is there a way to use map variable after awk command? Because I have tried to print map -like in my question- and does not print anything.

Comment: awk and the shell cannot share variables. You can copy simple values from the shell to `awk` but not the other way around, and you cannot copy complex values from the shell.

Comment: Then, is there an another way solution without awk by filtering  coloumns and building an assocative array?

Comment: Depends on the complexity of your problem. If all fields are separated by `|` then you can do: `while IFS='|' read k x v; do map[$k]=$v; done < $inputfile`. Notice that `x` is not used, so `v` will have the value of the 3rd column.

Comment: If more than 3 coloumns exists v holds 3th and other values (4th, ...). Prividing an extra value solves this problem. But for this problem there should be an another solution. This solution relies on constatnt data count. Thank you @janos for your patient and interest.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44013/discussion-between-janos-and-tyilmaz)